# Por que temos que usar ?> <?php quando usamos eval no conteúdo de um script php?

Tags: php, eval

Eu dei uma olhada no código-fonte do laravel 3 e vi o seguinte código:

```
eval('?>'.$__contents);
```

Em outras ocasiões, já vi algo como:

```
$content = file_get_contents('file.php');
eval('?>' . $content . '<?php');
```

Por que temos que usar `?>` e `<?php` quando usamos a função `eval` em um conteúdo de um script PHP?

Existe alguma razão especial pra isso?

Comment: você não tem que usar obrigatoriamente. O eval pega um conteúdo de uma string e valida como código PHP. Como vc esta incluindo um arquivo PHP provavelmente tem a tag "<?php" dentro dele que vai dar conflito com a tag de abertura (<?php) que esta no arquivo que esta chamando eval. Mesma coisa pra tag de fechamento. Então basicamente ele fecha a tag PHP no eval, inclui outro script abre a tag para continuar o script

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Como funciona o `eval`:

O `eval` executa uma *string* como uma execução normal do PHP, exemplo:

```
$x = 2;
$y = 3;
$z = eval('return $x + $y;');
eval('echo $z;');
```

O exemplo acima irá imprimir `5` na tela, pois na linha 3 o eval retornou o resultado da soma das variáveis `$x` e `$y`
e na linha 4 o `eval` imprimiu na tela com `echo`. Agora já temos uma ideia de como o `eval` funciona.

#### Por que usar `'?>'`:

```
$content = file_get_contents('file.php');
eval('?>' . $content . '<?php');
```

Imagine que a estrutura do arquivo `file.php` começa assim:

```
<?php
  // faça algum procedimento...
```

Então quando o eval executar ele vai abrir a tag do PHP, que no caso já está aberta pelo código atual que está executando o eval,
então nesse caso o `eval` deve fecha-la:

```
$content = file_get_contents('file.php');
eval('?>' . $content);
```

Essa execução ficaria:

```
$content = file_get_contents('file.php'); // apartir da próxima linha é a execução do `eval`
?><?php
  // faça algum procedimento...
```

Assim mesmo que o arquivo começasse com text (ou HTML) não haveria problemas:

```
$content = file_get_contents('file.php'); // apartir da próxima linha é a execução do `eval`
?><html>
     <head>
     <!-- restante do código -->
```

#### Fechar ou não a *tag* `?>` no `eval`?

No caso de fechamento é a mesma coisa, porém um pouco mais complicada em alguns casos.

Imagine agora que o arquivo `file.php` termine com

```
// Termino dos procedimentos
?>
```

Então nesse caso deve-se reabrir a *tag* do PHP para que o PHP continue a execução, senão as linhas de código após o `eval` serão impressas como texto, exemplo:

```
$content = file_get_contents('file.php');
eval('?>' . $content.'<?php');
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (user, pass) VALUES ('admin', '123456')";
```

No exemplo acima, se o `$content` fechar a tag php `?>` e se ela não fosse reaberta, as próximas linhas, como a da variável `$sql` seria impressa na tela para quem quiser ver. Isso seria um grande problema, já que o PHP permite e até é recomendável não fechar a TAG quando não há saída no buffer.

A maneira mais segura de evitar esse problema é verificar todas as linhas do código, e ver se existe ou não uma última ocorrência da tag de fechamento `?>`.

Exemplo de rotina para verificar se  a tag PHP está aberta ou fechada.

```
function checkTagPHP($linhas){
   $php = NULL; 
   foreach ($linhas as $linha) {
      $aber = strrpos($linha, '<?php');
      $fech = strrpos($linha, '?>');

      if ($aber > -1 && $fech > -1)
        $php = ($fech < $aber);
      else if ($aber > -1)
        $php = TRUE;
      else if ($fech > -1)
        $php = FALSE;
   }
   return $php;
}
$php = checkTagPHP($arrayDeLinhasDoCodigo);
// Após o loop
// $php == NULL  -> Não existe tag PHP no código
// $php == TRUE  -> Tag PHP aberta
// $php == FALSE -> Tag PHP Fechada
```

Assim você pode tomar a decisão de fechar ou não a tag PHP:

```
$content = file_get_contents('file.php');
$execute = '?>' . $content;

if (!checkTagPHP($content)) // Se Tag php estiver fechada
  $execute .= '<?php';

eval($execute);
```

<sub>**Obs.:** Os código acima não foram todos testados, podem haver algum erro de sintaxe.</sub>

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir esse caso de ativar o modo HTML dentro do `eval` e isso afetar o código PHP após o `eval`: http://ideone.com/4zra5T

Answer (score 3):

O `eval` do PHP espera receber um trecho de **código** válido, porém permite alternar para o "modo HTML". Por exemplo, este trecho, adaptado de um exemplo do manual

```
eval('echo "In PHP mode!"; ?>In HTML mode!<?php echo "Back in PHP mode!";');
```

dá a seguinte saída:

```
In PHP mode!In HTML mode!Back in PHP mode!
```

Ou seja, o `eval` "cospe" de volta o conteúdo que estiver em modo HTML, se ele for devidamente informado de que está nesse modo.

Os trechos que você citou na pergunta levam isso em conta, e tentam garantir que o conteúdo passado ao `eval` como uma variável qualquer (`$__contents` ou `$content`) seja interpretado em modo HTML. Ou seja, esse código foi feito para lidar com conteúdos deste tipo:

```html
<h1>HTML Normal</h1>
<h2><?php echo $valorVindoDoBanco ?></h2>
...
```

Sem a precaução de forçar a entrada no modo HTML com `?>`, esse código geraria um erro de sintaxe ao ser executado pelo `eval`.